# How to determine strength of singularity in solution of nonlinear differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system, singularity

I've been playing with a boundary value problem consisting of a fourth-order, nonlinear, inhomogeneous differential equation (containing two parameters $P$ and $Q$) and four or five boundary conditions.  By "four or five", I mean the following four:

1. $f\left(1\right) = 1$
2. $f'\left(1\right) = 0$
3. $f''\left(1\right) = 0$
4. $f\left(0\right) = 0$

together with an additional condition $f\left(0\right)f''\left(0\right) = 0$, which is not entirely distinct from boundary condition 4.

I've got solutions (for lots of values of the parameters $P$ and $Q$) to the differential equation with boundary conditions 1-4, obtained using a finite difference shooting method.  Now I need to verify whether the additional condition is satisfied, by checking whether $f''\left(x\right)$ is singular at $x = 0$, and if so whether the singularity is strong enough to prevent $f\left(x\right)f''\left(x\right)$ vanishing.  Visual inspection of the numerical results suggests that $f''\left(x\right)$ probably is singular at $x = 0$.  In an attempt to assess the strength of that singularity, I've substituted an ansatz $f\left(x\right) \simeq F_0x^n$ as $x \to 0$ into the differential equation (as per first step of the Frobenius method) to get an indicial equation.  The possibilities I found were $n = 0$ (ruled out by boundary condition 4), $n = 1$ (a doubly degenerate solution), $n = 9P/\left(9P-2\right)$ (consistent with boundary condition 4 only if $P > 2/9$, consistent with matching the inhomogeneity in the differential equation only if $P > 10/9$), and $n = 5/4$ (which directly matches the inhomogeneity in the differential equation, but needs a specific value of $F_0$ to do so).

Well, so far so good: $f\left(x\right)f''\left(x\right) \to 0$ as $x \to 0$ in any of those power-law forms.  However, the degeneracy of the $n = 1$ solution suggests to me that there's some additional, non-power-law form that I haven't tested.  How do I go about finding and testing it, please?  I've tried the method of reduction of order, but just get an intractable-looking third-order equation.

If anyone really wants to know, the differential equation is

$$12P\left(f\left(x\right)\right)^3f''''\left(x\right)+12\left(3P-1\right)\left(f\left(x\right)\right)^2f'\left(x\right)f'''\left(x\right)+4\left(3P+2\right)\left(f\left(x\right)\right)^2\left(f''\left(x\right)\right)^2+12\left(P-1\right)f\left(x\right)\left(f'\left(x\right)\right)^2f''\left(x\right)-\frac{9P^2}{Q^4}x = 0$$
It comes from a fluid mechanics paper from the 1930s (doi:10.1098/rspa.1939.0089).

**Additional information:** I tried a more general ansatz
$$f\left(x\right) \simeq F_0T^n\left(\ln\left(x\right)\right)^m$$
as $x \to 0$.  This   With this ansatz, the leading three orders of terms in the differential equation ($\sim x^{4n-4}\left(\ln\left(x\right)\right)^{4m}$, $\sim x^{4n-4}\left(\ln\left(x\right)\right)^{4m-1}$, $\sim x^{4n-4}\left(\ln\left(x\right)\right)^{4m-2}$) are balanced (only) if $n = 1$ and $m = 3/4$ (or with the $m = 0$ forms we already know about).  This form is consistent with boundary condition 4, and does *not* satisfy the additional condition.  However, it looks to me like this solution is not valid because terms $\sim x^{4n-4}\left(\ln\left(x\right)\right)^{4m-3}$ in the differential equation pose a solvability condition that cannot be satisfied by any straightforward "next term" in the asymptotic series.